# How to load non-Vue.js components within Vue-router routes, specifically Backbone Marionette Views

Tags: javascript, vue.js, backbone.js, routes, vue-router

While migrating from Backbone to Vue.js, I would also like to replace the current Backbone.js router with vue-router, while still loading some existing Backbone views. I'm looking for a way to load a Backbone view or arbitrary JS upon resolution of a vue-router route.

```
this.routes = [
  { path: 'myRoute', component: /* callback or non-vue component */ }
]
```